# Adding a dictionary to another dictionary C#

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

Is it possible to add a `dictionary` to another `dictionary` that contains different dictionary values?

```
Dictionary<String, Func<String>> d1 = new Dictionary<String,Func<String>>();
Dictionary<String, Func<String,String>> d2 = new Dictionary<String, Func<String,String>>();
Dictionary<String, Dictionary> dHolder = new Dictionary<String, Dictionary>();
dHolder.add("key",d1);
dHolder.add("key",d2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you use the `IDictionary` interface, which all dictionaries (no matter what type parameters they use) inherit from.

```
Dictionary<String, Func<String>> d1 = new Dictionary<String,Func<String>>();
Dictionary<String, Func<String,String>> d2 = new Dictionary<String, Func<String,String>>();
Dictionary<String, IDictionary> dHolder = new Dictionary<String, IDictionary>();

dHolder.Add("key1", d1);
dHolder.Add("key2", d2);
```

However, you'll need to go through the pain of unboxing the values when you retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but not quite the way you have written.

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, ObjectTypeA>();
var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, ObjectTypeB>();
var holder = new Dictionary<string, IDictionary>();

holder["key1"] = dict1;
holder["key2"] = dict2;
```

The only issue you have is now you've lost your generic types, so you need to check what type of dictionary you have when you take the key out.

```
var val = holder["key1"];    //Returns an IDictionary
var dictType1 = holder["key1"] as Dictionary<string, ObjectTypeA>;

//dictType1 will be null if it isn't a Dictionary<string, ObjectTypeA>
```

So you will have to do some type checking/conversion at some point, but you can still interact with it as an [IDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx) if you don't need strong typing.

```
holder["key1"]["newKey"] = new ObjectTypeA();    //Works
holder["key1"]["newKey2"] = new ObjectTypeB();   //Runtime exception
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be making TValue of `dHolder` an `Object` and then cast it to relevant type after retrieval.

```
    Dictionary<String, Func<String>> d1 = new Dictionary<String, Func<String>>();
    Dictionary<String, Func<String, String>> d2 = new Dictionary<String, Func<String, String>>();
    Dictionary<String, Object> dHolder = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
    dHolder.Add("key1", d1);
    dHolder.Add("key2", d2);

    Dictionary<String, Func<String>> val1 = dHolder["key1"] as Dictionary<String, Func<String>>;
    Dictionary<String, Func<String, String>> val2 = dHolder["key2"] as Dictionary<String, Func<String, String>>;
```

Remarks:

- `as` operator returns `null` if cast fails.
- You can also use `TryGetValue` method of the dictionary to safely retrieve value by its key.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This was very helpful.